How can I deal with questions about support of an ongoing feature?
I met a question that was asking which Web browsers do support an incoming Web API. By "incoming" I mean there is at least one implementer, there is a well advanced specs PR, but the usual compatibility aggregators (Can I use and MDN) don't have a page yet even though the compatibility tests are written, since last week.
So it is actually very possible to answer the question today, but I would have to come again to update the answer tomorrow and every time a new browser adds support for the feature. There is also a risk that the feature is actually never implemented in the other browsers and never makes it as an official Web API. It basically asks us to either know the future, or at least take a bet on it, or to be so committed that we'll keep coming back to update our answer over the years.
When looking at all the close reasons we have, I can't see one that fits the bill. The closest might be the old "too broad", but with the new version it doesn't really match since the question is actually clear enough and has enough details for us to provide an answer. I'd even go as far as to consider it on-topic, but still I believe it's not "useful" for future readers and may even be problematic since the answers could become wrong.
I considered using the least bad reason and post a comment explaining why this question didn't really fit our model, but that doesn't seem great.
Another possibility I thought of would be to write a canonical Q/A myself teaching how to check for such information, and then use it as a dupe target; but I'm not sure that question would be on-topic, nor if it would be good etiquette...
There was already this question (thanks Ryan M) but it's terribly old and points to close reasons that don't exist anymore.
So here I am, asking for the community's guidance over this edge case.

I'd close as off-site resources request.

@M-- I thought of that too, but I don't think it's really asking for such an off-site resource. We as reviewers may think of it because we know it's not the kind of resource that SO can deal with, and thus we know it requires info not yet available, but from the asker's POV I'm afraid it could send them off. Moreover the sub-title for this close reason is "This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers." which doesn't apply here. (Besides, would you mind posting this as an answer? It would be good to see the community's take on it over other propositions).

I would personally downvote, not a useful question for Stack Overflow. It is a slice of time question, not one with longevity. The actual canonical resources for such information will be updated when it's ready to be used and resources such as MDN are not unwilling to list features that are properly supported by only one browser.

Such a question sounds on-topic to me.
However, as you point out - it is annoying to maintain.
Maybe the correct answer to the question is something to the effect of "It is currently in flux" and consider updating it only at major developments with the feature. Or just check every 6 months or so, if you do not want to keep track of it all the time. Also consider making the answer a community wiki to encourage other users to also update with relevant changes.

Yes, I agree it is at least not off-topic. Then, there is obviously the anwserer's pain of having to maintain their answer, and I think you handled it pretty well, but there is also the pain of future readers that would come in between the updates. IOW, I wonder if such a Q/A would really be useful to other future readers? I think that in the general case, people don't ask about such things in here because (at least for Web APIs) compat aggregators do a pretty good job at this and people don't need to come to SO for this. But, such question may be on-topic, and still not a good fit for SO.

@Kaiido SO is meant to be a repository for knowledge and we've always said that if some information exists somewhere else, it doesn't mean it shouldn't also be on SO. With that said, we've also had the understanding that not every question could or would be answered. It might be that it gets an answer years later. So if the question is "Does X work?" the answer "Yes" comes after years when it actually does. Or a "No" after it was finalised that whatever X was would not be ratified. Or whatever. In any case, no answer is still acceptable.

I would lean toward saying it's okay.
The main problem is the question of who's going to keep it updated, given that the thing is constantly changing. Ex. calls to mind https://caniuse.com/, MDN compat data, CppReference Compiler Support page- none of which are really maintained by the authoritative sources of the status info they aggregate (mostly volunteer-maintained if I understand correctly), and all have to do with tracking compliance/completeness of multiple implementations of a standard(s). Stack Exchange has a mechanism to kind of enable that: Community Wiki. Quoting the FAQ post on the Community Wiki feature:

Why have Community Wiki posts?
One of the goals of the website is to be a continually evolving source of good information. Community Wiki posts help enhance the wiki aspect of the site.

The main effect of relevance of marking a post as Community Wiki is

A much lower reputation (100 instead of 2000) is needed to freely edit a community wiki post originally made by someone else.

Hopefully and ideally people keep such posts up to date, but we're all volunteers here. Nobody has a contractual responsibility to keep their post up to date. I think the reality is that a lot of this stuff probably goes stale and stays that way. But... I don't think that concern is necessarily a reason to not try (however idealistic that is).
I definitely don't think such requests should be closed as "off-site resource requests". Even if they're written as requests for off-site resources, they could probably be re-written as requests for that information to be on-site.

I don't think I've ever engaged in maintaining such an answer, but I myself have answered questions that

Deal with the evolving support of a single general feature of something that only has one implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77232931/11107541
An evolving experimental API (I gave up on continually inlining the API as it kept changing): https://stackoverflow.com/a/77456264/11107541
Deal with the history of language features (motivated to post by recent new language changes) https://stackoverflow.com/a/77835325/11107541
Deal with a lack of established convention on how to do something, and there being many differing opinions from prominent voices https://stackoverflow.com/a/78209338/11107541

I'm sure that some day those posts will find themselves needing an update. As long as my interest holds in the subjects, I'll probably (maybe) catch that info and be there to update them.
It's not much, but I think it's honest work (actually the amount of issue tickets I'm subscribed to notifications on, and the time I spend keeping up with them every day has grown to become non-trivial).

Funny that this comes up now, since just recently, there was discussion about updating community wikis with latest versions of things (see Should we always update the [java] version?).
Also loosely relevant: How to efficiently avoid "have they added this feature yet" questions (which I have answered as well).

Yes I feel you, I also have answered a few (actually a lot of) questions where an emerging technology would solve the issue, and since I like to contribute to specs and to lurke at new PRs there, I often see how these actually evolve in real time and take the time to update my previous answers as much as I can. But truth be told, it's a real work to do so... And while I like the idea of CW, on the many ones I wrote almost none have been edited by someone else than myself... Still that's probably the one solution I'd personally prefer. Let's see how others think.

@Kaiido if you're already doing the work to keep your own answer posts up to date, by all means, keep earning the rep for it (making a post community wiki means you don't earn rep. see the linked FAQ). switching a post of yours to Community Wiki is generally your own choice and up to whether you want to.

That completely depends on how and what the question is asking.
If it's "When does X support Y?", I'd say it's a request for an off-site resource. Look at X's issue tracker.
If it's "Does X support Y?", I can probably be on-topic, but if there's not much more to the question, I'd say it's not useful and should be downvoted.
If the question is more in-depth, mentions some specs, and basically asks for help interpreting the spec/support/implementation, then the question is probably on-topic.
But again, that completely depends on the individual question.
Likewise, answers like "We don't know", "It's in flux" and to a lesser extent "It's in development", etc aren't really good answers.
They probably should've just been a comment.

The case at hand is a question asking "Which browsers support this feature", I do believe it's on-topic. The particular question that raised this meta question does certainly warrant a downvote, it's of low quality anyways and I prefer not to link to it here even though it can be found, but regarding close votes vs answer it's exactly in the gray area you describe and I'm looking for a more general guidance as to how to handle these questions in that exact gray area.
